# Display csv meteo data

Tags: csv, grib

I have a grib file which has been converted into a .csv format. I have a web app which contains a chart, so i want to show my csv file's data on my chart but i don't know how to manipulate the file.

My file looks like that:

```
   X,           Y,          Latitude,       Longitude,     VOGRD_201304100000

 292,    1,    0.000000,  -50.530000,            0
 300,    1,    0.000000,  -49.170000,            0
 301,    1,    0.000000,  -49.000000,            0
 302,    1,    0.000000,  -48.830000,            0
 303,    1,    0.000000,  -48.660000,            0
 304,    1,    0.000000,  -48.490000,            0
 305,    1,    0.000000,  -48.320000,            0
 306,    1,    0.000000,  -48.150000,            0
 307,    1,    0.000000,  -47.980000,            0
 308,    1,    0.000000,  -47.810000,            0
 309,    1,    0.000000,  -47.640000,            0
 310,    1,    0.000000,  -47.470000,            0
 311,    1,    0.000000,  -47.300000,            0
 312,    1,    0.000000,  -47.130000,            0
 313,    1,    0.000000,  -46.960000,            0
 314,    1,    0.000000,  -46.790000,            0
 315,    1,    0.000000,  -46.620000,            0
 316,    1,    0.000000,  -46.450000,            0
```

I don't know what to do with all these parameters. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you please add more details?